# Receive phonestate and change hardware state in background

Tags: android

In my app, I need to check for the phonestate, and if the phonestate is "RINGING", I want to off the WiFi and Bluetooth in the device.

Should I use a `BroadcastReceiver` or instead place it in a service for the specified purpose?

I tried just like this code blocks, with my requirements:

http://androidword.blogspot.com/2010/10/how-to-use-broadcast-receiver.html

Answer (score -1):

To receive the Phon state change event is necessary to use a `BroadCastReceiver` also you need to have the READ_PHONE_STATE permission. see [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20210127130519/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/01/get-phone-state-when-someone-is-calling_22.html) tutorial for more details.